# How does the JSR-133 cookbook enforce all the guarantees made by the Java Memory Model

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, cpu, cpu-cache

My understanding, is that the [JSR-133 cookbook](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) is a well quoted guide of how to implement the Java memory model using a series of memory barriers, (or at least the visibility guarantees).

It is also my understanding based on the description of the different types of barriers, that StoreLoad is the only one that guarantees all CPU buffers are flushed to cache and therefore ensure fresh reads (by avoiding store forwarding) and guarantees the observation of the latest value due to cache coherency.

I was looking at the table of specific barriers required for different program order inter-leavings of volatile/regular stores/loads and what memory barriers would be required.

From my intuition this table seems incomplete. For example, the Java memory model guarantees visibility on the acquire action of a monitor to all actions performed before it's release in another thread, even if the values being updated are non volatile. In the table in the link above, it seems as if the only actions that flush CPU buffers and propagate changes/allow new changes to be observed are a Volatile Store or MonitorExit followed by a Volatile Load or MonitorEnter. I don't see how the barriers could guarantee visibility in my above example, when those operations (according to the table) only use LoadStore and StoreStore which from my understanding are only concerned with re-ordering in a thread and cannot enforce the happens before guarantee (across threads that is).

Where have I gone wrong in my understanding here? Or does this implementation only enforce happens before and not the synchronization guarantees or extra actions on acquiring/releasing monitors.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> StoreLoad is the only one that guarantees all CPU buffers are flushed to cache and therefore ensure fresh reads (by avoiding store forwarding) and guarantees the observation of the latest value due to cache coherency.

This may be true for x86 architectures, but you shouldn't be thinking on that level of abstraction. It may be the case that cache coherence can be costly for the processors to be executing.

Take mobile devices for example, one important goal is to reduce the amount of battery use programs consume. In that case, they may not participate in cache coherence and `StoreLoad` loses this feature.

> I don't see how the barriers could guarantee visibility in my above example, when those operations (according to the table) only use LoadStore and StoreStore which from my understanding are only concerned with re-ordering in a thread and cannot enforce the happens before guarantee (across threads that is).

Let's just consider a volatile field. How would a volatile load and store look? Well, [Aleksey Shipilëv has a great write up on this](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/on-the-fence-with-dependencies/), but I will take a piece of it.

A volatile store and then subsequent load would look like:

```
<other ops>
[StoreStore]
[LoadStore]
x = 1; // volatile store
[StoreLoad] // Case (a): Guard after volatile stores

...

[StoreLoad] // Case (b): Guard before volatile loads
int t = x; // volatile load
[LoadLoad]
[LoadStore]
<other ops>
```

So, `<other ops>` can be non-volatile writes, but as you see those writes are committed to memory prior to the volatile store. Then when we are ready to read the `LoadLoad` `LoadStore` will force a wait until the `volatile store` succeeds.

Lastly, the `StoreLoad` before and after ensures the volatile load and store cannot be reordered if the immediately precede one another.

Answer (score 1):

The barriers in the document are abstract concepts that more-or-less map to different things on different CPUs. But they are only guidelines. The rules that the JVMs *actually* have to follow are those in JLS Chapter 17.

Barriers as a concept are also "global" in the sense that they order *all* prior and following instructions.

> For example, the Java memory model guarantees visibility on the acquire action of a monitor to all actions performed before it's release in another thread, even if the values being updated are non volatile.

Acquiring a monitor is the *monitor-enter* in the cookbook, which only needs to be visible to other threads that contend on the lock. The *monitor-exit* is the release action, which will prevent loads and stores prior to it from moving bellow it. You can see this in the cookbook tables where the first operation is a normal load/store, and the second is a volatile-store or monitor-exit.

On CPUs with Total Store Order, the store buffers, where available, have no impact on correctness; only on performance.

In any case, it's up to the JVM to use instructions that provide the atomicity and visibility semantics that the JLS demands. And that's the key take-away: If you write Java code, you code against the abstract machine defined in the JLS. You would only dive into the implementation details of the concrete machine, if coding only to the abstract machine doesn't give you the performance you need. You don't need to go there for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got that `StoreLoad` barriers are the only type that enforce some particular behavior. All of the barriers, abstractly, enforce exactly what they are defined to enforce. For example, `LoadLoad` prevents any prior load from reordering with any subsequent load.

There may be *architecture specific descriptions* of how a particular barrier is enforced: for example, on x86 all the barriers *other than* StoreLoad are no-ops since the chip architecture enforces the other orderings automatically, and `StoreLoad` is usually implemented as a store buffer flush. Still, all the barriers have their abstract definition which is architecture-independent and the cookbook is defined in terms of that, along with a mapping of the conceptual barriers to actual ISA-specific implementations.

In particular, even if a barrier is "no-op" on a particular platform, it means that the ordering is preserved and hence all the happens-before and other synchronization requirements are satisfied.